# SAX Parsing(end element) tag of tag

Tags: java, android, xml, saxparser

I'm trying to parse an xml with SAX Parsing(end element) however when I try to parse the img tag it brings null

Here's the code Im using for Parsing using EndElementListener then I add it to my database.. here's the important part..

```
        item.setEndElementListener(
                new EndElementListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void end() {
        ...

                });

        item.getChild(TITLE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
            @Override
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setTitle(body.trim());
            }
        });
        item.getChild(LINK).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
            @Override
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setLink(body);
            }
        });


        item.getChild(PUBDATE).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
            @Override
            public void end(String body) {
                currentMessage.setDate(body);
            }
        });


            item.getChild(DESCRIPTION).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
                @Override
                public void end(String body) {
                    currentMessage.setDescription(body);
                    currentMessage.setBrief("empty");

                }
            });

            item.getChild(IMGURL).setEndTextElementListener(new EndTextElementListener() {
                @Override
                public void end(String body) {
                    System.out.println(body);
                    currentMessage.setImgUrl(body);
                }
            });



        try {
            Xml.parse(jsonString, root.getContentHandler());
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

XML

```
<item>
 <title>Title</title>

 <description>
 <![CDATA[ ****
]]>
</description>

<image>
<url>
  http://"....:"
 </url>
  </image>
</item>
```

Comment: Can you show your parsing code too?

Comment: added the important part